# How to add plugins to Neo4j Docker Container at build phase instead of dowloading plugins at container run?

Tags: docker, neo4j, neo4j-plugin

I need my neo4j service to use few plugins. My Neo4j Docker build file is :

```
FROM neo4j:3.5.14
ENV NEO4J_AUTH='neo4j/password'
ENV NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT='yes'
ENV NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc", "graph-algorithms"]'
RUN echo "dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*" >> ./conf/neo4j.conf
```

The part `ENV NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS='["apoc", "graph-algorithms"]'`

will download the listed plugins on container run and install them.

But, i have to run this container in a restricted environment , and i do not have internet access.
I cannot download the plugins on container run.

**What can i do to add these plugins at the build phase itself, so that they come ready with the image? **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try building and deploying your docker in a non-restricted environment, install everything, and then:

```
docker commit your-docker your-new-image-with-all-installed
docker save your-new-image-with-all-installed > your-image.tar
```

After that, you can take this image to your restricted (without internet) environment and deploy with:

```
docker load < your-image.tar
docker run ...
```